# Why was I banned from flagging...?

Tags: support, flag-ban

I just noticed I got banned from flagging and wonder why.

I suspect a manual ban, as I can't see any logic behind my recent flags. And the flags that got declined are already from a few days back, so not super recent.

I admit I had three recent flags declined.
I flagged two answers as NAA's on April 10, which got declined. Looking back they are indeed apples, to use Shog's [excellent analogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/284827). Very rotten apples nonetheless, but okay I get why those were declined.

The third declined flag was a custom flag, asking to protect a question, as I saw multiple answers on that question on the LQP review queue. Fair enough if a moderator decides it is not enough to protect that question.

For more details, see an excerpt of my flagging page.

[image]

Comment: So what's your question exactly, since you seem to understand the technical reason for the ban, and don't seem to object to the decisions that were made?

Comment: @BoltClock I dont know the technical reason, as I raised plenty of helpfull flags after the declined flags. Hence I suspect a manual ban. But then I would like to have confirmation of that + an explanation.

Comment: @Luuklag mods have no ability to manually ban/unban users from flagging - it's completely automated based on the ratio of recently declined vs helpful flags. (as a note - it looks like the ban is only for another 26 hours anyway...)

Comment: Thx for clarifying @JonClements. Ill close this as dupe to a post where the mechanism is explained. If you happen to know a more appropriate dupe, feel welcome.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405